# jscrollpane not reinitializing in IE

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using the fantastic scrollbar replacement plugin - [jScrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#)

I have a table which I append rows to via a json request that gets made to the server when the user scrolls to the bottom.

Everytime I make this request, upon completion I reinitialize the scrollpane via the starndard method as shown below:-

```
var myLayout;


//initialize sidebar

myLayout = $("#MySplitter").layout({
     defaults: {
     size: "50%",
     onresize: function () {
        var api = $('#toppane-wrapper').data('jsp');
        api.reinitialise();
    }
   },

    center: {
      size: "0px",
      onresize: function () {
        var api = $('#toppane-wrapper').data('jsp');
        api.reinitialise();
    }
   },  
    south: {
     size: "50%",
      onresize: function () {
        var api = $('#bottompane-wrapper').data('jsp');
        api.reinitialise();
    }
   }


});
```

So essentially when the panel resizes due to the increased content, the scrollpane should reinitialize and detect the new height, adjusting the scrollbar accordingly.

This works perfectly in every browser I have tested on apart from IE 9.

I'm at aa complete loss as to why this might be.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Just a small observation, you could have also said: this works in every browser except [...]. We could have filled in the dots :P

Comment: Sorry, I felt it was best to give as much information as possible. :-P

Comment: Press F12, are you seeing any errors when you click on console after reloading the page?

Comment: I've tried that and no errors are shown sadly.

Comment: The code you have posted is valid, there error must be elsewhere.

Comment: sigh - I've been battling with this for around 4 hours now... and as soon as i ask here, i find the problem.  The pane had to be set to overflow:hidden.  It was fine without it in all browsers but IE typically.

Answer (score 2):

Foolishly I was looking everywhere else other than CSS for the source of this problem.

It turns out in order for the pane to resize dynamically in IE, it must be set to overflow:hidden.  Curiously this is not necessary in any other browser.